# Sort group of records that are resulted from ORDER BY FIELD

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In a MySQL table, I want to sort the group of records that I get by `ORDER BY FIELD()`

More specifically,
Suppose, I ran the following query:

`SELECT name,status,date FROM memberTickets ORDER BY FIELD(status,7,10,3,4) ASC`

and got the following result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|    name    |    status    |            date           |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    A       |      7       |    2015-05-05 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    B       |      7       |    2015-05-07 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    C       |      7       |    2015-05-03 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    D       |      10      |    2015-05-08 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    E       |      10      |    2015-05-01 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    F       |      10      |    2015-05-05 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    G       |      10      |    2015-05-05 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    H       |      3       |    2015-05-03 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    I       |      3       |    2015-05-08 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    J       |      3       |    2015-05-01 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    K       |      4       |    2015-05-05 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    l       |      4       |    2015-05-07 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, I want to sort the records in such an way so that the position of the group of records remain same(as set by order by field), but the records in each group are sorted with the date attribute as descending order, like the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|    name    |    status    |            date           |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    A       |      7       |    2015-05-07 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    B       |      7       |    2015-05-05 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    C       |      7       |    2015-05-03 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    D       |      10      |    2015-05-08 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    E       |      10      |    2015-05-05 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    F       |      10      |    2015-05-05 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    G       |      10      |    2015-05-01 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    H       |      3       |    2015-05-08 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    I       |      3       |    2015-05-03 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    J       |      3       |    2015-05-01 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    K       |      4       |    2015-05-07 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    l       |      4       |    2015-05-05 00:00:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Any idea or suggesions how to do that?

Comment: `order by field(...), date desc`? you can order on as many fields (and expressions) as you want.

Comment: @MarcB Thank you. It works in the way you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify usualy as many sorting parameters as you want for `ORDER BY` like this

```
SELECT name,status,date FROM memberTickets ORDER BY FIELD(status,7,10,3,4) ASC, date DESC
```